# How to load all css and js at a time in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How to load all css and js on one request

Here is a sample HTML document that similarly includes many CSS and JavaScript files

> > < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/960framework.css">
> >
> > < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/base.css">
> >
> > < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/navigations.css">
> >
> > < script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jQuery.js">
> >
> > < script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/functions.js">
> >
> > < script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/handlers.js">

... more then

its make 6 request but i want load all js and css at a time (only one request )

so i try

for css

> > allStyles.css.php //
> >
> > include("cssReset.css");
> >
> > include("960framework.css");
> >
> > include("base.css");

for js

> > allScripts.js.php
> >
> > include("jQuery.js");
> >
> > include("functions.js");
> >
> > include("handlers.js");
> >
> > include("ajax.js");
> >
> > include("navigations.css");

and just call

> > < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/allStyles.css.php">
> >
> > < script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/allScripts.js.php">

all js and css loaded but css and js not woring n page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is not sending the appropriate content type header in the response. for you add these line s to the top of the page

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
<?php header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>
```